# can't find cn=module,cn=config entry

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm new to openLdap , I am setting up a module for monitoring using on-line configuration (OLC) based on this guide : https://blog.kmp.or.at/monitoring-openldap/.

i use ldapmodify as bellow :

```
ldapmodify -x -H ldap:/// -D "cn=config"   -W -f module.ldif
```

result is :

```
modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
```

content of module.ldif is :

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {1}back_monitor
```

i understand that i can't modify on non-existing entry so i tried to add a new entry for DN = (cn=module,cn=config).

i tried to create new dn using :

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulepath:  /etc/openldap/libexec/openldap
```

but i got this error

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Do i really need to create this DN , or it must be created during setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this entry is created during setup.

It seems you missed to setup `slapd.d` directory for online configuration (OLC) :

```
slapcat -f /path/to/slapd.conf -F /path/to/slapd.d
```

Also, choose the appropriate SASL mechanism for authentication :

- Either use `EXTERNAL` mechanism with `ldapi:///` transport (relies on the client process uid and gid via Unix sockets) :

  ```
  `ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f module.ldif`
  ```
- Or `LDAP` (default) with options `-D` and `-W` for binding :

  ```
  ` ldapmodify -x -H ldap://example.com -D cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com -W -f module.ldif`
  ```

Comment: thank you , for the answer , can you please specify how to re-install an existing openldap with the option to find this entry created

Comment: Reinstalling openldap depends on your os and you'll have broken system dependencies. You can try also `slapcat -b cn=config`, if you have nothing just reset your config using a working slapd.conf file (it's a step you may have missed : it takes a .conf file and creates the corresponding slapd folder with cn=config etc. so that you can use OLC) : `slapcat -f slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d` (path may vary demending on your system).

Comment: to understand what happened i found that the openldap overlay is static not dynamic , that's why we can not find the entry , but something wonders me is that they say there is a built in module called slapd ,which doesnt need to be loaded: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html#entries http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch11/overlays.html.   so maybe the module i needed is already loaded. how can i verify this.

Comment: Yes, but still in the end non built-in modules can be loaded via `cn=module{0},cn=config` so that entry should exist in slapd.d (once setup) anyway.

Comment: Yes you are right : i used the command slapd -VV to show the built in modules and i can find that my module is in the list so no need to reinstall it again . Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This might help others as well,

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
cn: module 
objectClass: olcModuleList
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap <Your Module Path>
olcModuleLoad: memberof.la <Youe Module Name>
```

Above LDIF will create a module under DB Schema if it does not exist.
Execute the following command to validate if it's created.

```
sudo ldapsearch -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config -LLL dn
```